# Android - how to align list view items to be nicely spaced left and right align?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to add an image to my ListView to make it look more like a button.  I would like the images to be a little smaller, maybe 60% of current.  And the images to lign up nicely on the right in a column.  Here is a screen of what I currently have:

[image]

and here is my list view xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_button" 
     >
</TextView>
```

any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

The ListView that contains this TextView is defined like this:

One note, the way I create and work with my Lists is with the ListAdapter, using code like this:

```
Question q = new Question ();
q.setQuestion( "This is a test question and there are more than one" );

questions.add(q);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Question>( this, R.layout.questions_list, questions);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Protip: Alt+PrtScr to take a screenshot of the current window. Or since you're on Windows 7, use the Snipping Tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the comment and advice that Frank Sposaro gave, you will be able to position your views correctly.

For your next problem, I advice you to make your own adapter similar to this:

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.row);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mImage);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            //Fill the views in your row
            holder.text.setText(questions.get(position).getText());
            holder.image.setBackground... (questions.get(position).getImage()));

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView image;
    }
```

In your onCreate:

```
ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mListView);
mListView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), questions));
```

Another example for a ListView with an Adapter can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11631714/1479570)

Answer (score 4):

Ahh. You are doing the correct thing using a compound drawable. Not sure if there is a better way to maybe have the spacing in your compound drawable expand, but I know this'll work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<View
    android:layout_height="64dip"
    android:layout_width="64dip"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically just pointing out using the align parent right and left. You may want to add some margins or padding to them. Also make sure to vertically center your elements.

Comment: thanks, trying it now.  Would you know how to also make the images appear to about 60% of their current size? They seem to have been made a bit too large.

Comment: Actually I am getting an error on the xml: Unbound prefix with the RelativeLayout :(

Comment: That's because xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" should have been moved up. I updated it

Comment: Ah yeah with your latest code, it compiled ok. Now trying to run it and see how it goes :)

Comment: Well. If it works just please upvote and accept. I pain stakingly typed in that xml into eclipse and then copied and pasted, lol. Wanted to make sure all the attribute names were correct.

Comment: ahh. I forgot to address your shrinking problem. There's an update. Just play with the dip values to get what you want

Comment: just ran it and it crashed with this exception :) java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: I think the ArrayAdapter that I use only works with strings and textViews.  Is it possible to set aside 10% of the sreen to the rigth and make the images as background image of that part of the screen?

Comment: Yeah. You didn't tell me you used an ArrayAdapter. Or else I would have saved my time writing all that code.

Last thing I can recommend is setting the width to match_parent and trying to use android:drawableEnd instead of drawableRight

Comment: sorry, I had not realized that the ArrayAdapter would be a problem in this case. :(