# How does ListView in Android works ? I'm confused

Tags: android, android-listview, android-relativelayout, android-arrayadapter

I was trying a simple list view in android.
I got an example from some website. It worked. Code below:

Main Layout File: (res/layout/main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
      android:orientation="vertical"  
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
      android:id="@+id/mainListView">  
    </ListView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Row File: (res/layout/simplerow.xml)

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:id="@+id/rowTextView"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:padding="10dp"  
 android:textSize="16sp" >  
</TextView>
```

Main Activity:

```
package com.windrealm.android;  

import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Arrays;  

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;  
import android.widget.ListView;  

public class SimpleListViewActivity extends Activity {  

  private ListView mainListView ;  
  private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
  @Override  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  setContentView(R.layout.main);  

  // Find the ListView resource.   
  mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

  // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
  String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                                  "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};    
  ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
  planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

  // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.  
  listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);  

  // Add more planets. If you passed a String[] instead of a List<String>   
  // into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items.   
  // Otherwise an exception will occur.  
  listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );  
  listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );  
  listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );  
  listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );  
  listAdapter.add( "Eris" );  

  // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
  mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );        
  }  
}
```

I was trying to add an image, not even dynamic. I just thought of adding a layout into the `simplerow.xml` file. But its not working.

Code below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/songs"
        android:src="@drawable/song_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/albumArt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/album"
        android:src="@drawable/albumart_shanghai" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/albumArt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/albumArt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/arrow"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

We can't add the Relative layout inside the ListView ?
Pls help me I'm struck with ListView from one month. I couldn't even move a single step :(
I'm newbie to java and XML. Pls someone show me the right path.

Comment: We can't add the Relative layout inside the ListView ? -- So what is exactly the problem you are facing? What is happening instead?

Comment: Try reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533819/android-how-to-align-list-view-items-to-be-nicely-spaced-left-and-right-align/11633979#11633979).. Maybe that will clarify

Comment: @AndroSelva, Then how actually it works ? I need to implement a design for each row. like an image for each row and 2 textview in it.
how can I achieve it ?

Comment: @praveenkumar What exactly is the problem you're facing? Do you get an exception? You don't see something on the screen? The list rows are not showing properly? etc

Comment: @Luksprog ya.. I get an exemption and asks me to close. nothing shows up..
i get error here `mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );`

Comment: @praveenkumar You should add to your question the exception you get from the logcat. See if `mainListView` is not `null` it might work to try and clean the project and run it again(menu `Project -> Clean`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to extend the ListActivity, like

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity{}
```

then you can simply specify the adapter as

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

You have a problem with your layout file, android list view id should be `@android:id/list`, android developer site says

> your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id
>   "@android:id/list"

**EDIT**

Basically the array adapter constructor signature you are using is,

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

But if you want to use more complex layout, use

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

where `textViewResourceId` should refer to the textview id in the layout.

This obviously results in, you can have the layout with multiple text fields but the given texts will be displayed in the textfield specified by the id.

Thus, to get your task done, you need to create your own adapter which extends the BaseAdapter. Within that adapter you need to override the

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}
```

method, in which you can inflate your layout and set the appropriate values.

I think you would have gotten at least some idea by this, then take a look on [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) most explained tutorial about listview.

Answer (score 1):

Vogella given a perfect understanding. please go through it. Its giving you even step by step information.

Answer (score 0):

**ListView Example**

**Layout File:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>
```

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

static final String[] NUM= new String[] { "1", "2", "3",
        "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
        "9", "10", "11", "12", "13" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_num,NUM));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: I have already did this and its working fine, I posted question here coz I don't know how to implement relative layout inside the listView row, now I have implemented the Realtive layout now I don't know how to add two textView in the row and send values to it.